# True Meaning of "Positive change is but a thought away."

Tags: phrase-meaning

I would like to know what the following sentence means.

> Positive change is but a thought away.

I know that the sentence is the same as "Positive change is only a thought away." However, I fail to understand "is only a thought away."

I expect that this sentence could mean one of the following two sentences.

> Positive change is a matter of how you think.

> Just a little more thought, and you can make positive change.

If you were to replace the first sentence with a plain English sentence, what would it be?

Comment: Thinking about how you will make a positive change is the first step to actions that bring that change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It only takes a thought to achieve a positive change.

One of the meanings of ***but*** (as an adverb) is:

> no more than; only. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=but%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsamf-SbndYrwaVU3Pip4ag3CJiggw%3A1662990036891&source=hp&ei=1DYfY5eANMeZhbIPm5OOqAE&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYx9E5KzdQHFE0bzrKVfMMcXmR8oj2t5Y&oq=but%20&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIJCCMQJxBGEPkBMgoIABCxAxCDARBDMgQIABBDMgUILhCABDIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIFCAAQgAQyBAgAEEMyCwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOgQIIxAnOhQILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAxDUAjoRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQrwE6CwguEIAEELEDENQCUABY5QNg2xBoAHAAeACAAeYBiAHfBZIBBTAuMy4xmAEAoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz))

***Only a + noun + away*** is a common expression that means that *it only takes that little to obtain something or get somewhere*. Think of *just a click away*. Here are some  ore collocations of this kind:

[image]

In your example *away* is used (metaphorically though) as an adjective with the meaning:

> distant in space or time ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/away))
>
> - a lake 10 miles away
> - the season is two months away

Note that *[but a](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but%20a%20*%20away&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)* is more formal than *only a* and even more formal than *just a*.